# How to quickly create a IPython shell in Emacs?

Tags: shell, emacs, ipython

When I do python development in emacs, I want an IPython shell available. Here is my current way of accomplishing this:

```
M-x ansi-term
```

Which prompts me with `Run program: /bin/bash`, which I replace with `/usr/bin/ipython`

It's often the case that I want another terminal in emacs, perhaps to run the app, so I do:

```
M-x rename-buffer
```

and change the name of the buffer to `ipython` so that I can change buffers easily, with having to remember which terminal was the IPython shell.

It seems that there would be a way to create an emacs command that would accomplish all of this with a few keystrokes, but I don't know the right way to begin, being fairly inexperienced with Emacs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the code:

```
(defun ipython ()
  (interactive)
  (ansi-term "/usr/bin/ipython" "ipython"))
```

Also, [smex](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Smex) makes it even faster to start.

Comment: I'm curious, what does `(interactive)` do?

Comment: `(interactive)` allows the command to be called with `M-x`. You can find out more
with `f1 f` `interactive`.

Answer (score 3):

Suggest to run IPython from a python-mode.

<kbd>M-x ipython RET</kbd> would be sufficient if python-mode.el is loaded.

python.el comes with comments in head how to configure, so <kbd>M-x run-python RET</kbd>  will open an properly named IPython-shell buffer.